# SQLiteException: near "references": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String CREATE_ASSIGNMENTS_TABLE= "create table "
        + ASSIGNMENTS + "(" + TITLE
        + " text not null, " + DESCRIPTION
        + " text not null, " + REFERENCES + " text not null );";
```

This is my create table query to create a table in SQLite.

I have three fields (`title,description,reference`). All are text fields. But when I execute  the code, I get the following Exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "references": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table ASSIGNMENTS(TITLE text not null, DESCRIPTION text not null, REFERENCES text not null);
```

It is pointing to an error in the `REFERENCES` field. But I couldn't find any syntax error there. Please help me out in this matter.

Comment: REFERENCES is a sqlite special keyword http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html . Change it with another name

Comment: change `references` to `ref`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REFERENCES` is a [keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in SQL syntax. Either change the column name or quote it in backticks:

```
`REFERENCES`
```